# What set do these parts belong to? Bag 4 with lots of dark red

Tags: set-identification

I cannot find these parts anywhere!
[image: Bag 4 with lots of dark red]

Answer (score 3):

Based on [4286597: PLATES W. BOWS 2X2](https://brickset.com/parts/4286597/plates-w-bows-2x2), [6114676: PLATE W. BOWS 2X1½](https://brickset.com/parts/6114676/plate-w-bows-2x1%C2%BD) and the ball socked elements, this bag is from [76104: The Hulkbuster Smash-Up](https://brickset.com/sets/76104-1/The-Hulkbuster-Smash-Up)

[image]